# variable is not correct get in jenkins docker.inside()

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, maven-docker-plugin

In docker plugin parallel situation, the x didn't get correct output in docker.image.inside,  and always get the last element in the array, is there any solution? Here is the example code,

```
node {
x_array = [1,2]
x_map = [:]
image = "centos:latest"
    for (x in x_array) {
        x_map[x] = {
        image = docker.image(image)
        image.pull
        image.inside("-t") {
             sh "echo $x"
        }
        }
    }
    parallel x_map
}
```

Here is the output:
2
2
While expect output:
1
2